# Beautifulsoup - get_text, output in a single line

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, line-breaks

I am trying to extract the text of the following page and save it into a single cell of a CSV file. However, I keep getting linebreaks at places where I don't see any "special" characters (ie even where there are no "\n", "\t", etc in the text). The second line of the CSV file also has more than one non-empty cell, instead of just saving the text into a single cell.

Here is the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#Python3.x
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, urllib, csv, re, sys
csvfile=open('test.csv', 'w', encoding='cp850', errors='replace')
writer=csv.writer(csvfile)

list_url= ["http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1025315/0000950127-05-000239.txt"]

for url in list_url:
 base_url_parts = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)
 while True:
    raw_html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html)

    #### scrape the page for the desired info 
    text_10k=[]
    ten_k=soup.get_text()
    ten_k=ten_k.strip().replace("\t", " ").replace("\r", " ").replace('\n', ' ')
    text_10k.append(ten_k)    

#Zip the data
    output_data=zip([text_10k])

#Write the observations to the CSV file
    writer=csv.writer(open('test_10k.csv','a',newline='', encoding='cp850', errors='replace'))
    writer.writerows(output_data)
    csvfile.flush()
```

I am sure my error is simple, but it's been months since I've used Python... I could definitely use a refresher. Many thanks!

EDIT: The output is too long to copy in full, but here is an example:

Line 1, Cell 1: ['-----BEGIN PRIVACY-ENHANCED MESSAGE-----\nProc-Type ..... -8-", 'The change in working cap
Line 2, Cell 1: tal is primarily attributable to the loss for the\nyear
Line 2, Cell 2: and the reduction in cash due to payments made on long-term notes payable.\n\n

I would like everything to be in a single cell (Line 1, cell 1), no linebreak characters. So:
Line 1, Cell 1: ['-----BEGIN PRIVACY-ENHANCED MESSAGE-----\nProc-Type ..... -8-", 'The change in working captal is primarily attributable to the loss for the\nyearand the reduction in cash due to payments made on long-term notes payable.\n\n

*Notice that an "i" goes missing in the word "capital" when it gets split between Lines 1 and 2. Not sure what causes the line to break this way.

EDIT2: I made it work by saving as a .txt file (which works fine as long as I open the output in Notepad++ or something similar). I still don't know why it would not work as a CSV, though.

Comment: What is the output you are getting, and what did you expect to get?

Comment: Can you update the example in your question? Also indicate what you found unexpected in that

Comment: where are you checking this? Everything is coming in a single line, though I would say what you are creating is not csv format at all

Comment: I know the get_text should create a single string (line), but the CSV file the code writes has more than one line when I open it (as shown above), even though there is only one file in the url list (and thus, should have only one -very long- string that comes from the get_text).

Comment: What you show as output can't be from the given source code because there the '\n' charactars are replaced by space. Also you have mixed up different file objects. The `csvfile.flush()` has no effect because you use another file object to append to the file.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that in `While True:` the program would end up stuck in a while loop forever. Changing that to `if url:` should let it run once per url. I should note, it would not run until I added 'lxml' as a parser for BeautifulSoup `soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'lxml'`). This does appear to put each url's information into a single cell. Because the amount of information in the cell is so large, it likely cannot be displayed in a standard spreadsheet.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Python3.x
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import csv

csvfile = open('test.csv', 'w', encoding='cp850', errors='replace')
writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

list_url = ["http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1025315/0000950127-05-000239.txt"]

for url in list_url:
    base_url_parts = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)
    if url:
        raw_html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'lxml')

        #### scrape the page for the desired info
        text_10k = []
        ten_k = soup.get_text()
        ten_k = ten_k.strip().replace("\t", " ").replace("\r", " ").replace('\n', ' ')
        text_10k.append(ten_k)

        #Zip the data
        output_data=zip([text_10k])

        #Write the observations to the CSV file
        writer=csv.writer(open('test_10k.csv','a',newline='', encoding='cp850', errors='replace'))
        writer.writerows(output_data)
        csvfile.flush()
```